# Multiple buttons in a one event handler not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

Below is the okButton_Click function where I am trying to add multiple buttons. I am getting error

> input string was not in a correct format

I have read other solutions regarding similar questions but still but I am having trouble fixing the code below. Any help would be appreciated.

Forgot to mention earlier that both buttons on individual basis work. Meaning, if I comment the first button, the second one works and vice versa.

```
protected void okButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    Button button = (Button)sender;

    // button info <asp:Button ID="triangleAreaButton" runat="server" Text="Calculate"
    // OnClick="okButton_Click" CssClass="btn btn-success" />
    triangleAreaResultLabel.Text = button.ID;
    TriangleProperties triangle =
        new TriangleProperties(int.Parse(baseTextBox.Text), int.Parse(heightTextBox.Text));
    triangleAreaResultLabel.Text = String.Format("({0} x {1}) / 2  = {2}", baseTextBox.Text,
        heightTextBox.Text, triangle.AreaOfTriangle().ToString());

    // button info <asp:Button ID="pythagorasTheoremButton" runat="server" Text="Calculate"
    // OnClick="okButton_Click" CssClass="btn btn-success" />
    hypotenuseLabelforPyT.Text = button.ID;
    TriangleProperties pythagorasTheorem =
        new TriangleProperties(int.Parse(heightTextBoxforPyT.Text),
            int.Parse(baseTextBoxforPyT.Text), 0);
    hypotenuseLabelforPyT.Text =
        String.Format("{0} ", pythagorasTheorem.PythagorasTheoremFindHypotenuse().ToString());
}
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: You are probably getting this from one of the `int.Parse` calls. Have you ensured that your textbox values are not empty and are valid string representations of `int` values? Please debug your code using a proper debugger and then update your question.

Comment: You need to not only figure out which line is causing the problem, but also which method call. The stack trace can help you with that. It's *probably* those int.Parse calls failing because you're not providing a valid int.

Comment: pythagorasTheorem object line

Comment: Both buttons on individual basis work. Meaning, if I comment the first button, the second one works and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this line gives you the error.

```
TriangleProperties pythagorasTheorem = new TriangleProperties(
        int.Parse(heightTextBoxforPyT.Text),
        int.Parse(baseTextBoxforPyT.Text), 
        0);
```

Take a look at the `int.Parse()` method [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx).

Under the exceptions this method may generate:

> **FormatException**   : s is not in the correct format.

So, the actual text in either of the text boxes is not a valid integer. Even if you have a white space at the end, like a `space` or a `tab`, that still won't work and will give you this error.

Instead of `int.Parse()` you should use `int.TryParse()`, [which will check if the conversion is possible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx), and will return `true` if so, and will return `false` if not possible. In the case of a valid conversion the `out` parameter will contain the converted value.

So your code should look something like:

```
if(int.TryParse(heightTextBoxforPyT.Text, out int heightVal) && 
   int.TryParse(baseTextBoxforPyT.Text, out int baseVal))
{
    TriangleProperties pythagorasTheorem = new TriangleProperties(heightVal, baseVal, 0);
}
else
{
    // Perhaps output an error message
}
```

Comment: I was going to suggest the exact same thing. I'd add `else` as well to notify the user that something went wrong and `base` may not be the best choice for variable name (isn't it reserved for accessing base class?)

Comment: @nurchi I agree, I didn't test this in the IDE simply copy-pasted the OPs code and made modifications. Thanks for pointing out, I'll make the changes.

Comment: Thank you, Sach. It works. However, I run into another issue. When I click the first button, the label text of hypotenuseLabelforPyT.Text automatically shows the second button's ID since I believe code suggest hypotenuseLabelforPyT.Text = button.ID;

Comment: That's a different problem, you should ask a different question.

Comment: I have figured it out by moving hypotenuseLabelforPyT.Text = button.ID; under if code block. Thanks for your help!